# Why my mysql doesn't use index?

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing

I'm tuning my query for mysql.
the schema has index of user_id (following..)
but the index is not used. why?

Env:
    MySQL4.0.27,MyISAM

SQL is the following :

```
SELECT type,SUM(value_a) A, SUM(value_b) B, SUM(value_c) C
FROM  big_record_table
WHERE  user_id='<user_id>'
GROUP BY type
```

Explain:

```
|table |type |possible_keys |key |key_len |ref |rows |Extra|

|big_record_table| ALL| user_id_key|||| 1059756 |Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort|
```

could you describe detail?

scheme is following:

```
CREATE TABLE `big_record_table` (
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
 `type` enum('type_a','type_b','type_c') NOT NULL default 'type_a',
 `value_a` bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
 `value_b` bigint(20) default NULL,
 `value_c` bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
 KEY `user_id_key` (`user_id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE big_record_table` please?

Comment: Thank you fore replying .I've written SHOW CREATE TABLE big_record_table

Comment: How many records has been read by this query?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `type` and `user_id` are not `indexed`.

Just a will run. You're not giving much to play with.

Comment: Thank you for replying . but I wanna get Why only user_id is not OK?

Comment: @ffffff you're grouping by `type`. If you get a huge bunch of results with the `user_id` they will all have to be read to find out about different types.

Comment: Thank you so much! If you know a documents listed in . I'm happy

Answer (score 0):

First, we don't see how your indexes are declared.  Can you get a dump of the tables?  In PostgreSQL you'd use `pg_dump` but I don't know how in MySQL.  Have you done an ANALYZE on the table?

Comment: Thank you . yes I've ANALYZEd

Comment: OK, but what about the table layouts.  I don't see how your indexes are defined.  Did you create an index on big_record_table?  How exactly was that index created?

Comment: I've wrote the scheme . could you give me why? Should I read source code of mysql optimizer?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that implicit type conversion is preventing your index from being used.  You have defined user_id as an int, but specified a string in the query.   This gives MySQL the option of either converting the string in the query into an int (which might not be accurate) - or convert every user_id in the database into a string to compare against the string in the query.

Short answer:  try removing the quotes in the query

```
SELECT type,SUM(value_a) A, SUM(value_b) B, SUM(value_c) C
FROM  big_record_table
WHERE  user_id=123
GROUP BY type
```

(where 123 is replaced with the correct user-id).